# D3 On click not working for circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a modified version of D3 + Google Maps, wherein, I'd like a modal to pop up when I click on an SVG circle.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();

// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.134249, 72.913608),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

function assign_dots() {
    $("#hour").text(hour);
    // Load the station data. When the data comes back, create an overlay.
    d3.json("stations.json", function (error, data) {

        var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        if (error) throw error;


        // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
        overlay.onAdd = function () {
            var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget).append("div")
                .attr("class", "stations");

            // Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
            // We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
            overlay.draw = function () {
                var projection = this.getProjection(),
                    padding = 10;

                layer.selectAll("svg").remove();

                var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
                    .data(d3.entries(data))
                    .each(transform) // update existing markers
                    .enter().append("svg")
                    .each(transform)
                    .attr("class", "marker");

                // Add a circle.
                marker.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", function(d){
                        return d.value[3][hour]*6;
                    })
                    .attr("cx", padding)
                    .attr("cy", padding)
                    .on("click", toggleExpand);

                // Add a label.
                marker.append("text")
                    .attr("x", padding + 10)
                    .attr("y", padding)
                    .attr("dy", ".31em")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        if (d.value[3][hour])
                            return d.key;
                    });

                function transform(d) {
                    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value[1], d.value[0]);
                    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                    return d3.select(this)
                        .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
                }

                function toggleExpand(d) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
                    console.log(d.value[2]);
                    console.log("Reaches here");
                }

            };
        };

        overlay.onRemove = function() {};

        // Bind our overlay to the map
        overlay.setMap(map);
    });
}
window.onload = assign_dots();

function progress_time() {

    hour = hour + 1;
    if (hour == 24) hour = 0;
    console.log(hour);

    d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
    assign_dots();
}

function regress_time() {

    hour = hour - 1;
    if (hour == -1) hour = 23;
    console.log(hour);

    d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
    assign_dots();
}
```

Basically, in the `assign_dots` function, when I am appending a circle to the marker, it should set an `onclick` function to be `toggleExpand`, but when I am clicking on an svg circle, nothing happens.

What can I be missing?

---

**Edit**

Here's the stylesheet:

```
html, body, #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

#map {
    border: solid;
}

.stations, .stations svg {
    position: absolute;
}

.stations svg {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.stations circle {
    fill: blue;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

And I have also included bootstrap.

For some reason, when I remove the bootstrap css, the `on click` starts working. What could the problem be?

Comment: There's a huge difference (behaviour-wise) between `.on("click", toggleExpand())` and `.on("click", toggleExpand)`. The former will call the function at the time of binding the event but will not do anything when the event fires. The latter will call the function when the event fires, but does not call the function at the time of binding.

Comment: @JSBob So, in my case, I need to use the latter, right? Why isn't it working still?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418320/bind-click-event-listener-to-map-marker-using-d3-and-js

Comment: @Mark not really. If you read my code, you'll see that I do have `overlayMouseTarget `.

Comment: I have a feeling that Google Map is listening to all clicks and not passing down to your circles.

Comment: I have been trying out stuff. Apparently, when i remove bootstrap from my code, the click works. Is there a compatibility issue?